# How can I access my time capsule through ssh?

Tags: network, time-machine, time-capsule, ssh

I am trying to reach the time capsule on a remote network. After following the [advice of another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70964/28232) I realised the router/network doesn't support NAT-PMP/UPnP and thus I get to configure the time capsule as available through icloud, but I'm never able to reach it outside of the network.

However, I am able to ssh into an old powerpc I have port mapped on the router to a static IP. Is there any way to tunnel the time capsule backup through ssh? I've also tried [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) which works perfectly to forward dns/http requests. But it doesn't seem to make time capsule backups available, since the finder doesn't show any shared devices on the network.

I would gladly try a solution like [FreeLan](http://freelan.org) but unfortunately their support goes back to 10.7 and the old PowerPC machine inside the remote network serving as entry only has 10.5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to forward TCP port 548, which is AFP (Apple Filing Protocol). This is the storage protocol used by Time Machine to access content on a Time Capsule.

Note: This will not necessarily make it possible for your remote systems to auto detect the Time Capsule - as any DNS information (Bonjour) you forward would probably be incorrect as it needs to be translated (i.e. a different IP-address).

Connect to the Time Capsule directly using the IP instead. From Finder select Go => Connect to Server and then enter: afp://123.123.123.123/

Substitute your own IP ofcourse!

Comment: Nice, it hadn't occurred to me to use a static ip. Browsing doesn't show up anything but with sshuttle I can indeed mount the remote time capsule with an IP address. So it's just the browsing which doesn't get forwarded with sshuttle.